# How does comparing a binary heap's root and root's children to the heap's array length help determine whether you have a min heap?

Tags: data-structures, priority-queue, binary-heap

Bellow is the method I'm confused by. Why do `k`, `right`, and `left` need to be greater than `n`?

```
// is subtree of pq[1..n] rooted at k a min heap?
    private boolean isMinHeap(int k) {
        if (k > n) return true;
        int left = 2*k;
        int right = 2*k + 1;
        if (left  <= n && greater(k, left))  return false;
        if (right <= n && greater(k, right)) return false;
        return isMinHeap(left) && isMinHeap(right);
    }
```

Comment: A binary heap is a complete binary tree which satisfies the heap ordering property. The ordering can be one of two types: the min-heap property: the value of each node is greater than or equal to the value of its parent, with the minimum-value element at the root.
[https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the length check is to ensure that you don't try to access an element off the end of the array. You have this code:

```
    if (k > n) return true;
    int left = 2*k;
    int right = 2*k + 1;
    if (left  <= n && greater(k, left))  return false;
    if (right <= n && greater(k, right)) return false;
```

Remember, `k`, `left`, and `right` are indexes to the backing array. They aren't actual values. So `if (k > n)` isn't comparing the node's value to the array length, it's making sure that the *index* is within the array bounds.

What `greater(k, left)` does is, essentially:

```
return a[left] > a[k];
```

Let's say that `k` is the index of a leaf node. Then `left` will be an index that's beyond the end of the array, and `greater` will try to access an element that doesn't exist in the heap. To prevent that, the code makes sure that `left <= n`.